# Metric and Pseudo-metric space for Riemann Integrable Function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

For the metric $$d(x,y)=\int_{a}^{b}|x(t)-y(t)|dt$$
The question asked whether it was defined on

i) the set of real-valued functions on $[a,b]$

ii) the set of real-valued Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$

I think for i), it defined both metric and pseudo-metric and for ii), it is not metric but it is pseudo-metric. (The example I thought of is step function.) But there were two parts I struggled with.

1) How do I prove that the (M1) for for both of these questions ? (It seems trivial for me, how to to prove it rigorously ?)

2) How do I prove that the example of step function is unable to fulfill (M2) of a metric ? In my proof, I require the definition that $$\int_{c}^{c}|x(t)-y(t)|dt = 0 .$$

Is this definition valid ?

Comment: $d(x,y)$ is not defined for all real valued functions $x$ and $y$.

Comment: What are M1 and M2?